# what is following left join sql statement doing?

Tags: mysql

Below is copied from high performance mysql book:

```
select film.film_id from sakila.film 
left outer join sakila.film_actor using(film_id) 
where film_actor.film_id is null;
```

I could not understand what it is doing. 
Does the where clause filter for `film_actor` before joining. If so, how does join performs (`film_id` is null already, how does it join with film using `film_id`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a standard SQL pattern for finding parent rows that have no children, in this case films that don't have an actor.

It works because missed left joins have all nulls in the missed joined row, and the where clause is evaluated after the join is made. Specifying a column that can't be null in reality in the joined row as being null returns only mussed joins.

Note also that you don't need `distinct`, because there is only ever one such row returned for missed joins.